# jQuery - Return items by selected SKU number

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a purchase receipt interaction where the user `clicks` a `SKU` number and all list `items` with the same `SKU` are `cloned` to a list to show all matching items with the same `SKU`.

Instead of appending the original list items, I want to return matching results to the `modal` so that if you click a different `SKU`, the results are replaced by the last selected `SKU`.

```js
$("li a").click(function() {
  var item = $(this).closest("li");
  var sku = $(this).html();

  var $parent = $("li#" + sku);
  $parent = $('<li id="' + sku + '">')
    .clone()
    .appendTo(".modal");
});
```

```css
ul {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0.9rem 0rem;
}

li a:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bullet {
  margin: 0.3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex
}

.modal {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="bullet blue"></div>
      <a>1234</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="bullet red"></div>
      <a>0808</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="bullet green"></div>
      <a>9011</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="bullet blue"></div>
      <a>1234</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="bullet green"></div>
      <a>9011</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="modal"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use `data` attribute in this case instead of using `.html()` to get the value

- Add the `data-sku` for each `<a>` with its number
- Filter the `li` which contains the `<a>` with the same `sku`
- change the modal with `.html()`
- **Be careful** When taking a clone of `li`s and append it to the `div.modal` it will be `<li>`s in `<div>` and that is an invalid structure so you need to change `<div.modal` to `<ul>` or you can create a `<ul></ul>` inside the `div.modal` and use `$('div.modal > ul').html(....)` .. Then you'll need to separate the `<ul>` in the css one for the `ul` in `.wrap` and another for `ul` in the `.modal`

```js
$(document).on('click',".wrap > ul > li:not(.appended) > a",function() {
  var sku = $(this).data('sku');    // get data sku
  var FilTer = $('a[data-sku="'+sku+'"]').closest('li').clone(); // filter li which contains same data sku and get clone from it
  $('.wrap > ul > li').removeClass('appended').filter(function(){ // remove the class `appended` from all the `wrap li`s then filter `li`
    return $(this).find('a[data-sku="'+sku+'"]').length; // return just the li which contains the a with data-sku
  }).addClass('appended'); // add class appended to this li
  $('.modal > ul').html(FilTer); // change the modal html with the filtered html
});
```

```css
ul {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0.9rem 0rem;
}

li a:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bullet {
  margin: 0.3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex
}

.modal {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="bullet blue"></div>
      <a data-sku="1234">1234</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="bullet red"></div>
      <a data-sku="0808">0808</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="bullet green"></div>
      <a data-sku="9011">9011</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="bullet blue"></div>
      <a data-sku="1234">1234</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="bullet green"></div>
      <a data-sku="9011">9011</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="modal">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation** To avoid cloning and appending on each click

- You need to set class (e.g: `appended`) to the appended `li`
- To get the click event work with the appended class you'll need `$(document).on('click',".wrap > ul > li:not(.appended) > a",function() {`
- It will be better to use `>` sign in selector to get only the `li` and `a` in `wrap` element

Comment: it keeps cloning if you click more than once. Is there a way to only clone once?

Comment: when I take the code into a pen the sku clones itself when clicked from inside of the modal https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/KjMNeb

Comment: @KyleUnderhill When you change the `modal` to `<ul>` instead of `div` the `.wrap > ul` catches also the `modal` ul .. you can use `<div class="modal"><ul></ul></div>` and in js use `$('.modal > ul')` like in updated answer .. OR you can use `ul:not(.modal)`  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KjNvNp  .. For me I prefer the `<ul>` inside the `<div class="modal">` to give me a good space to style in css